# NSString isEqualToString - Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Why do I get an Unrecognized Selector sent to instance at

```
doesExist = [myStr isEqualToString:@"Hello"];

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"Found %d peripheral as a result of scanning", myListOfPeripherals.count);

    NSString *strMACId = [advertisementData valueForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
    NSLog(@"%@", strMACId);



    [timerConnectionTimeout invalidate];
    PeripheralCell * objPeripheralCell;

    NSLog(@"Found Peripheral with Name: %@ RSSI data:%@ AdvData: %@", peripheral.name, peripheral.RSSI, advertisementData);

    // Check if the Peripheral already exists in your collection - if no add it.
    if ([self peripheralExistsWithMacId:strMACId] == false)
    {
        // New peripheral - Add it to the list of myPeripherals
        objPeripheralCell=[[PeripheralCell alloc] init];
        [myListOfPeripherals addObject: objPeripheralCell];
        objPeripheralCell.peripheral=peripheral;
        objPeripheralCell.rssi=RSSI;
        objPeripheralCell.peripheralMacId = strMACId;

    }

}




-(BOOL) peripheralExistsWithMacId:(NSString *)strMacId
{
    BOOL doesExist = false;
    for (int i=0; i<myListOfPeripherals.count; i++)
    {
        PeripheralCell *objPeripheralCell = myListOfPeripherals[i];
        NSString *myStr = objPeripheralCell.peripheralMacId;
        NSLog(@"Comparing %@ with %@", myStr, strMacId);
        **doesExist = [myStr isEqualToString:@"Hello"];**
        if (doesExist)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return doesExist;

}
```

Error -->>  `-[NSConcreteData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7970e90`

Update:
 NSLog(@"%@", strMACId) yields <00ff6e62 61bacad8>  How can I tell that this is not a NSString Object

Comment: because objPeripheralCell.peripheralMacId is not an NSString object.  Can you show where you declare that variable and where you assign it?

Comment: In The Header
`@interface PeripheralCell : NSObject

`@property (retain) CBPeripheral *peripheral;
`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *rssi;
`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *peripheralMacId;

`@end

In the Implementation 

#import "PeripheralCell.h"

`@implementation PeripheralCell
`@synthesize peripheral, rssi, peripheralMacId;
`@end

Comment: @OneGuyInDc Update your question with that info so people can read it.

Comment: So its hard to add code to comments.  As rmaddy pointed out 
NSString *myStr = objPeripheralCell.peripheralMacId;

Comment: You also need to update your question with the code that actually assigns a value to the `peripheralMacId` property. The error clearly indicates you are assigning an `NSData` instance and not an `NSString`.

Comment: @OneGuyInDc, you should alter your question, not post code in comments

Comment: According to your comment, your declaration looks ok.  Where do you assign it a value?

Comment: Updated my Code with the Caller as well

Comment: Consider actually reading the message and considering what it's telling you.

Comment: What is the output of `NSLog(@"%@", strMACId);`? Hint - update your question with the actual output.

Comment: @HotLicks - Sorry I don't understand your comment.  I realize it is telling me that unrecognized selector but I don't get how.

Comment: @OneGuyInDc He means to read the entire error. The important part is `[NSConcreteData isEqualToString:]`. This means you are trying to call the `isEqualToString:` method on a class of type `NSConcreteData`. This clearly tells you that it is not a string like you expected.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", strMACId) yields <00ff6e62 61bacad8>  How can I tell that this is not a NSString Object

Comment: That's the output of an `NSData` object. A string would show the actual string value. That output matches the error. This means your `advertisementData` doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: A way to tell which class you have is to log the class.  `NSLog(@"The class is %@", [somePtr class]);`.  In the debugger you can do `po [somePtr class]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your line of code:

```
[advertisementData valueForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
```

Is returning an NSConcreteData and you are assigning it to a pointer of type NSString.  The reason you are not receiving any code errors in Xcode is that it thinks you know what you are doing in assigning to a specific type of pointer.  Then it sees you calling `isEqualToString` on that pointer which it thinks is an NSString and thereby sees that call as completely logical and functional.  If you added a line of code (or an NSLog even) checking if the object is actually an NSString you would see that it is not.

```
if([strMACId isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    //This will return false for your case, and never get in here
}
```

What you need to do is read the value in from the NSDictionary and then convert it to an NSString object.  You can use something like:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

But you are going to have to be careful as to the encoding.  There are methods to loop through encoding styles until you get one that will decode your NSData without error, but I'm not certain that your data can be properly decoded into an NSString.  Another option would be to change the type of `PeripheralCell.peripheralMacId` into an NSData and compare datas to get what you need.

Comment: Completely understood

Comment: What kind of encoding does NSLog use?  You are correct - iterating thru all of the encoding styles does not give the output I expect yet NSLog output matches perfectly.

Comment: NSData *pMACIdData = [advertisementData valueForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
    NSLog(@"Data Is %@", pMACIdData);


yields - 2014-01-07 15:04:27.156 XXXXXXXX[1321:c07] Data Is <00ffa435 fcf394d5>

Comment: You said the NSLog matches perfectly.  That doesn't look like it output a string to match perfectly...

Comment: The NSlog is outputting a string 00ffa435 fcf394d5 out of NSData.  My question is what encoding does it use to get that?.  As I try different encodings I always get a null string

Comment: That is not a string.  That is a list of bytes surrounded by the <> brackets.  If you try to convert that to an NSString you are getting null because the first byte in that list is a null character (00, terminating character for strings).  I suggest you save this as an NSData instead of as an NSString.  Then you can compare NSData to NSData later in your comparisons.

Comment: What encoding can be used so that a byte of 00 in a NSData byte array can be converted to a ASCII String of "00"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44738/discussion-between-oneguyindc-and-putz1103)